# JRUBY - Passing a ruby class to a generic parameter

Tags: ruby, class, generics, interface, jruby

```
//Job.java
package br.eti.mribeiro;

public interface Job {
    void teste();
}


//Teste.java
package br.eti.mribeiro;

public class Teste {
    public void executaJob(Class<? extends Job> classe){
        try {
            Job job = classe.newInstance();
            job.teste();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

#jruby_teste.rb
require File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), 'teste_jruby.jar')

java_import 'br.eti.mribeiro.Job'
java_import 'br.eti.mribeiro.Teste'

class TesteJob
  include Job
  def teste
    puts "123456"
  end
end
Teste.new.executaJob(TesteJob.class)
```

I guess the code above is pretty self explaining, i hava a Ruby class that implements a Java interface, and i want to pass that class back to a Java class. However, when a execute the ruby code i get the following error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: org.jruby.RubyClass
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:359)
        at br.eti.mribeiro.Teste.executaJob(Teste.java:6)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:452)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:313)
        at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:45)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:313)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:163)
        at teste.invokeOther18:executaJob(teste.rb)
        at teste.RUBY$script(teste.rb:14)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:599)
        at org.jruby.ir.Compiler$1.load(Compiler.java:111)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:822)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:814)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:752)
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:574)
        at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:409)
        at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:304)
        at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:231)
        at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:200)
```

Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

ps: teste_jruby.jar is a jar file i exported with the java code.

Thanks,
Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

[kares](https://github.com/kares) solved it for me! It's posted on  [GitHub](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/3454)